# How to join tables between the sheet and query in Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets

In Sheet2 I have the following columns with ~1000 rows

```
[ NAME      EMAIL-ADDRESS       PHONE       PRODUCT ]
```

In Sheet3 I have the following columns with 3000 rows

```
[ company   first_name  last_name   full_name   email   amount ]
```

I need to get the the result by joining sheets, that is

Sheet3 email = Sheet2 EMAIL ADDRESS

```
first_name last_name (from Sheet3), email address (from Sheet3), PRODUCT (from Sheet2), amount (from Sheet3)
```

How do I get this, its ok even if it is a custom function in Google Sheets

I tried with

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A1:D3000, "Select B & ' ' & C WHERE B='" & Sheet3!$E2 & "'", 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191BgTa9sMtU7aJjDuOFk21y5z_6zppwmkndvWmkvc38/edit?usp=sharing).

You may use `filter` + `vlookup` in a single formula:

`=FILTER(
{Sales!B14:B,Sales!C14:C,Sales!E14:E, vlookup(Sales!E14:E,{People!B2:B,People!D2:D},2,), 
Sales!F14:F},Sales!E14:E<>"")`

`FIlter` will convert `vlookup` into `ArrayFormula`. This will return PRODUCT from sheet "People".

I renamed sheets to give them more meaningful names.

- "Sales" = "Sheet3"
- "People" = "Sheet2"