# How to join tables using Query or Vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have 2 sheets

people sheet has

```
[company    first_name  last_name   full_name   address_line1   address_city    address_state   address_zip address_country telephone   email   order_id    order_date  order_time  processor   order_type  order_currency  commission  campaign_id]
```

sales sheet has

```
[DATE   PROSPECT NAME   EMAIL ADDRESS   CONTACT METHOD  PRODUCT RESULT  NOTES ]
```

How do I make the report to generate when people.email = sales.EMAIL ADDRESS and display the records only if they match (Not all of sales sheet)

Report fields are

```
full_name
EMAIL ADDRESS
PRODUCT
commission
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/191BgTa9sMtU7aJjDuOFk21y5z_6zppwmkndvWmkvc38/edit#gid=1530945570)

Please try to use basic formula for joining sheets + query to skip some rows.

Basic formula:

`=FILTER({Sales!B14:B,Sales!C14:C,Sales!E14:E, vlookup(Sales!E14:E,{People!B2:B,People!D2:D},2,), Sales!F14:F},Sales!A14:A<>"")`

The formula you need:

`=QUERY(FILTER({Sales!B14:B,Sales!C14:C,Sales!E14:E, IFERROR(vlookup(Sales!E14:E,{People!B2:B,People!D2:D},2,), "do not show"), Sales!F14:F},Sales!A14:A<>""),"select * where Col4 <> 'do not show'")`

## How it works

It uses `iferror(expression, "do not show")` to replace `#N/A` error with the text "do not show".

Then it uses query to hide rows with value "do not show":

`"select * where Col4 <> 'do not show'"`

Basic formula and the question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48165026/5372400)

---

**Notes about usage:**

1. `Sales!B14:B,Sales!C14:C,Sales!E14:E` are some columns you need to select first
2. `IFERROR(vlookup(Sales!E14:E,{People!B2:B,People!D2:D},2,)` will return column from "People", it is column `People!D2:D`. Please note that columns `Sales!E14:E` and `People!B2:B` are both containing a key, in the sample it is e-mail list.
3. `Sales!F14:F` is a column to return next.
4. filter condition `Sales!A14:A<>""` is to skip empty rows from original sheet. You may also add other conditions into a filter.
5. `query` part will shorten the report and skip values where keys (emails) do not match. You may add other conditions into a query.

Note. Query language in Google Sheets does not have `joins`, and provided solution is a workaround. It shows how to make a join with a help of `vlookup` function in Sheets.

- The provided formula gathers rows from sheet "Sales" and makes `vlookup` to sheet "People". You also may want to make vice-versa report: collect data from "People" and 'vlookup` data from "Sales".

**"Vice-versa" report:**

`=QUERY(FILTER({vlookup(People!B2:B ,{Sales!E14:E, Sales!B14:B, Sales!C14:C, Sales!E14:E},{2, 3, 4},), People!B2:B, IFERROR(vlookup(People!B2:B ,{Sales!E14:E, Sales!F14:F},2,),100500)},People!A2:A<>""),"select * where Col5 <> 100500")`

**note!** In this formula used numeric value 100500 to skip values because query works with the single data type (number or text).

---

Please comment here if you have any questions about how it works.

Comment: I've added some notes to the answer. Query language in Google Sheets does not have joins, and provided solution is a workaround. It shows how to make a join with a help of `vlookup` function in Sheets. Hope this helps.

Comment: Added the formula to make a report from sheet "People" as a main sheet (where the unique ID's are stored.