# How to join two google sheets tables in app script by comparing a foreign key

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Lets say we have two tables in two sheets

sheet - NAME

| Name | id |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | 1 |
| Christine | 2 |

sheet - AGE

| id | age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 25 |

is there a way to get the following table in to a third sheet using appscripts without manually iterating through each row?

| Name | id | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 1 | 20 |
| Christine | 2 | 25 |

I tried iterating through tables and joining, but the most of the parts of the app script code cannot be generalised to other scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Alternate Solution

You could iterate through these tables using the [JavaScript Array map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) method like this:

```
function sampleJoinTables(array1,array2){
  var result = array1.map(x => array2.map(y => y[0] === x[1] ? [x[0],x[1],y[1]] : null).filter(z => z).flat());
  return result;
}
```

### Sample

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**If the id is always aligned by row (as in the example data).**

`=query({query({Name!A1:B},"select Col1, Col2 where Col1 is not null"),query({Age!A1:B},"select Col1, Col2 where Col1 is not null")},"select Col1, Col2, Col4 where Col2 = Col3")`

---

**If the id is not aligned  by row.**

`=FILTER({A1:A,B1:B, vlookup(B1:B,D1:E,2,0)},A1:A<>"")`

h/t : @MaxMakhrov [How to join tables using Query or Vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48168744/1330560)

**Name**

[image: name]

**Age**

[image: age]

**Results**

[image: Results]