# Looking up values and adding them to a table in a dynamic sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two Google sheets (tabs) for an inventory database, which is automatically updated every two hours by a script:

1. Sheet "A" containing all the products in our warehouse: 
   Product_ID, Product_Name, Colour, Size, Price
2. Sheet "B" containing the activity/transactions:
   Product_ID, Transaction_ID, Quantity

I would then like to build a new sheet "C" based on a formula, with the following columns:
Product_ID, Transaction_ID, Quantity, Product_Name, Colour, Size, Price

Basically joining the two on "Product_ID".

The reason I cannot just do this manually is that Sheet A and B are automatically regenerated every 2 hours based on changes in the database.

The purpose of all of this is to enable flexible querying and calculations on the stock using the power of the spreadsheet  :)

I tried joining using Google Query Language but seems there isn't syntax in there for joining separate tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join tables between the sheet and query in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164516/how-to-join-tables-between-the-sheet-and-query-in-google-sheets)

Comment: The answer posted by Max Makhrov in the "possible duplicate" includes a fully worked, sample spreadsheet. IT deals with exactly the scenario that you are working with.